# send a variable to another component (observable)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Using Angular CLI. I have a component and a variable there:
*this.name = 'someValue'*
I want to send the variable to another component using Observable but can't manage it. who can help?

Comment: try using a `shared service` with an `observable Property` on which you subscribe from Component2 and call the `.next(somevalue)` function from component1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @marvstar mention about shared service is the best option if components does not have relation `Parent->Child`. So if your components are separated you should use `shared service`, basics of this solution you can find on [official angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). Summing up in `shared service` you have to create `Source (Subject) of data` for example `public DataSource: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>` and `Observable for subscribing changes in source` it would look like `public Data$ = this.DataSource.asObservable();` and whenever you want to emit new data you just simple need to call service `this.SharedService.DataSource.next(dataToPass)` which will emit new data for all observers of this source. So in your component which should get data you should subscribe to observer `this.SharedService.Data$.subscribe(data => handleData(data))` and that's it.

However If you components has relations `Parent->Child`, then it's much simplier. If you want to send data from `Parent` to `Child` you just simple use `@Input() dataToPass: any` (highly recommended to incude type of data) on child `ts` file and in parent `html` file `<child-component [dataToPass]="someParentVariable"></child-component>`.

For Child->Parent relations you have to use `@Output` with `EventEmitter` something like this:

```
child.component.ts
export class ChildComponent {
   @Output dataToPass: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>;

   private sendDataToParent() {
      this.dataToPass.emit(someData);
   }
}

parent.component.html
<child-component (dataToPass)="handleData($event)"></child-component>

parent.component.ts
/* code of parent component */
public handleData(dataFromChild) {
   //do somethnig.
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you/ just one quastion. What is data => handleData(data) in this.SharedService.Data$.subscribe(data => handleData(data))?

Comment: and why  dataSource is private, I can't you it in any component

Comment: Sorry, firstly thought about adding special method to emit code, but I was too tired. I will fix that :), for your first question `data` is simply what you pass in `next(dataToPass)` and `handleData(data)` is just you custom method to handle passed data :).

Comment: Best explanation I've seen yet.  Also, don't forget to put the service in the app.module.ts or whatever @NgModule is appropriate for your setup.

Answer (score 1):

1. See next very useful tutorial:
   https://youtu.be/I317BhehZKM
2. Check documentation:
   https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction